# Get all the data related to similar column values in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table,

```
+-----------------|---------------|--------------------|---------------|
  id              |  hostName     |        timestamp   |     memToal   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1              | A             | 1402643486558      |    1891852    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2              | B             | 1402643486558      |    1891852    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3              | A             | 1402643486558      |    1891852    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
   4              | C             | 1402643486558      |    1891852    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get all the information related to each distinct column value, but I know the host names only at runtime. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: Without details no one can suggest you..

Comment: Show table structure & few data and what you had tried .

Comment: Which host names? What are you talking about?

Comment: Show the sample output that you are looking for. That might help us understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
  select
    hostName,
    group_concat(distinct timestamp) timestamps,
    group_concat(distinct memToal) memTols
  from mytable
  group by hostName
```